# Strange parameter substitution in CMD (BAT) file

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, cmd

I have written a powershell script that I'd like to be able to run from a batch script on Windows.

The powershell script is located in `blizzard-main.ps1`.

The CMD script looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -command "& { . %~dp0%\blizzard-main.ps1; Blizzard-Main %1}"
:EOF
```

The strange error I get when running this is:

```
. : The term 'C:\Users\mzr\Documents\GitHub\ProductionTools\Blizzard\Dist\Blizzard\bin\1'
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.

At line:1 char:7

+ & { . C:\Users\mzr\Documents\GitHub\ProductionTools\Blizzard\Dist\Blizzard\bin\1 ...
[SNIP]
```

If I debug the script using echo like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO powershell -command "& { . %~dp0%\blizzard-main.ps1; Blizzard-Main %1}"
:EOF
```

I get this interesting output:

```
powershell -command "& { . C:\Users\mzr\Documents\GitHub\ProductionTools\Blizzard\Dist\Blizzard\bin\1}"
```

So clearly something has been messed up. If I remove the `%1`, the script is executed, but then the first parameter isn't being passed the way it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error myself:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO powershell -command "& { . %~dp0%\blizzard-main.ps1; Blizzard-Main %1}"
:EOF
```

should be changed to

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO powershell -command "& { . %~dp0\blizzard-main.ps1; Blizzard-Main %1}"
:EOF
```

(I had an extra `%`.)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the `%~dp0` includes a trailing slash, so you may not want to add yet another trailing slash onto it. Also, I'd recommend always putting double quotes around the path to a file, just in case there's a space in the path.

Change your command line to this:

```
powershell -command "& { . \"%~dp0%blizzard-main.ps1\"; Blizzard-Main %1}"
```